# How do I fix "The plugin "External Tools" could not be loaded. An error occured: Plugin loader "python 3" was not found)" error in GEdit?

Tags: 20.04, python3, gedit, plugins

I'm using GEdit version 3.36.2 pre-installed with Ubuntu 20.04.1.
I wanted to enable the **External Tools** plugin of GEdit, but I'm unable to do so.

When I click on the *External Tools* option, I get ⛔ symbol.

[image: Gedit preferences]

When I close GEdit and reopen it, the option is turned off.

[image: Gedit preferences]

If I enable it, I'll again get the same ⛔ symbol.

How do I fix this issue?

---

Edit 1:
`gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` was not installed when I asked this question. After [jokerdino's suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55435077#55435077) in the Ask Ubuntu General Room, I installed `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` using this command: `sudo apt install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0`.

I noticed an error message after installing `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0`.

[image: Error message in gedit]

> **The plugin "External Tools" could not be loaded**
> An error occured: Plugin loader "python 3" was not found

I am not sure if I could see this error message before installing `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0`. Maybe I didn't place the mouse pointer on the symbol (for few seconds) the first time when I noticed the symbol or maybe it could be some other reason. I don't know.

[jokerdino suggested me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55438092#55438092) to open gedit from terminal and check if I got any specific error while turning on External Tools. I did get an error in the terminal.

```
** (gedit:14693): WARNING **: 20:21:59.976: Error initializing Python Plugin Loader: PyGObject initialization failed
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'gi'"))

** (gedit:14693): WARNING **: 20:21:59.976: Please check the installation of all the Python related packages required by libpeas and try again

(gedit:14693): libpeas-WARNING **: 20:21:59.976: Loader 'python3' is not a valid PeasPluginLoader instance
```

I guess Python 3.8.2 was pre-installed with my Ubuntu installation. I wanted to upgrade to Python 3.8.3. So I followed the instructions mentioned in this website [Install Python 3.8.3 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - TechPiezo](https://techpiezo.com/python/install-python-3-8-3-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/).
At the end of the article, two suggestions were given. First is to replace (or overwrite) already installed version 3.8.2 of Python; second is to install Python v3.8.3 alongside the Python v3.8.2. I followed the first option.

Comment: Try to reinstall Gedit: `sudo apt purge gedit gedit-common` and then `sudo apt install gedit`.

Comment: @user3140225 I reinstalled gedit using the commands which you've mentioned. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to enable External Tools.

Comment: See if this related question helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045114/gedit-manage-external-tools-menu-option-doesnt-appear

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix In the question which you have sent, the files and directories below `~` are owned by root. In my case they are owned by me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112686/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-kulfy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must and should rollback to default Python version, i.e., 3.8.2 in 20.04 since there are some libraries which are required by some packages installed in the system only for the default version of Python that may not be available or compatible with other versions. Since you've installed Python 3.8.3 from source, the files were copied in `/usr/local/` and `/usr/local/bin/python3` is created which a symlink, a.k.a, symbolic link or soft link, of `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`.

The [default value](https://askubuntu.com/a/386635/816190) of `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, thus given priority and the reason behind invoking Python 3.8.3 instead of 3.8.2 whenever `python3` or `python3.8` is called (since default Python is installed in `/usr/bin`).

To revert back to the default `python3` won't take much time for you. You have 3 options to revert back.

1. **Removing the symlink:** Just delete `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Yes that's it.
2. **Recreate symlink:** You can make `/usr/local/bin/python3` to point to `/usr/bin/python3.8` or `/usr/bin/python3` (which is already a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3.8` as per [your message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55439040#55439040) in general room).

   To recreate symlink, use [`ln`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) with `s` and `f` options, i.e.,

   ```bsh
   sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3 # You may replace /usr/bin/python3.8 with /usr/bin/python3 as explained above
   ```
3. **Giving `/usr/bin` priority** (overkill): Edit `/etc/environment` and place `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`.

   **Warning!!!** You should handle `/etc/environment` with care. Don't touch or do anything unless you know what you're doing.

   **Alternatively**, you can place `PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` in `/.profile`.

   Once done, logout and relogin to make changes take place.

Since you've installed Python 3.8.3 from source, you need to delete files manually as Python don't provide `uninstall` option for `make`. To delete them run:

```bsh
# From /usr/local/bin
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm 2to3 2to3-3.8 easy_install-3.8 idle3 idle3.8 pip3 pip3.8 pydoc3 pydoc3.8 python3 python3.8 python3.8-config python3-config
# From /usr/local/include
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/python3.8
# From /usr/local/lib
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo rm -r libpython3.8.a pkgconfig python3.8
# From /usr/local/man/man1
cd /usr/local/man/man1
sudo rm -r python3.1 python3.8.1
# From /usr/local/share/man/man1
cd /usr/local/share/man/man1
sudo rm -r python3.1 python3.8.1
```